# Common Footer for all Pages

Tags: jquery-mobile

In my JQM project I have several pages accessible from the footer.

However I'm struggling with the concept that for each `data-role="page"` I need to include the footer markup.

Isn't there a way I can specify the footer once for the entire application and have the buttons `ui-btn-active` set to the page I am on automatically?

Comment: R you using any framework or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [persistent footers](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html), but you will have to write the code for the footers in every page. With class `ui-btn-active` you can set the active page.

Are you using any mobile framework? Some of them allow you to specify the html code in a common place and include it in every page. For example, [Rhomobile](http://www.rhomobile.com/).

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem since the OP wants to write footer once for the whole application, not for every single page. It's clear from the question. -1

Comment: However, it solves the problem of setting the page he is on. Do you know a better solution?

Comment: I also want to know the answer. I'm currently putting the question on favorite.

Comment: Edited answer. Maybe it's not the final solution, but it could help.