# jQuery Mobile common footer for all pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using `jQuery Mobile` and in my project there are `several pages`.

I want that all pages to `share a common footer` without putting the footer in each page, I want it to be at only at one place and from there it will appear in all pages.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Common Footer for all Pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826544/common-footer-for-all-pages).

Comment: I already saw this, but what i want, is, to put the code for footer only at one place for all pages

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10919445/190695

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$('[data-role=page]').on('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
            $("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=footer]").load("footer.html", function(){
                $("#" + event.target.id).find("[data-role=navbar]").navbar();
            });
        });
```

Refer to this post

[Jquery Mobile Same Footer on Different Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906189/jquery-mobile-same-footer-on-different-pages/10908726#10908726)